# SyntaxError: Parse Error only happens in safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, safari

Im getting SyntaxError: Parse Error, only on safari. Here is the code in question.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form").transload({
        auth: {key: "b7deac9c96af6c745e914e25d0350baa"},
        flow: {
            encode: {
                "use": ":original",
                "robot": "/video/encode",
                "preset": "flash",
                "width": 480,
                "height": 320
            },
            encode_iphone: {
                "use": ":original",
                "robot": "/video/encode",
                "preset": "iphone"
            },
            export: {
                "use": ["encode","encode_iphone"],
                "robot": "/s3/store"
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

I am using transloadit a jquery plugin. which works on every other page and is loading fine on safari by the looks of it.

The errors is on line 44 which is

```
export: {
```

Can anyone see anything wrong with that page?

Comment: can't see the code in question. please correct the post.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> The following words are used as keywords in proposed extensions and are therefore reserved to allow for the possibility of future adoption of those extensions.
>
> class enum    extends super const export  import

[ECMAScript Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf), section **7.6.1 Reserved Words**

Other interpreters might be more liberal about them, which might explain that it only gives a `SyntaxError` in JavascriptCore (Safari's javascript interpreter).

Comment: I'd like to add that the parser error is also triggered when JavaScript keywords (e.g. `delete` and `new`) are used as property keys. A solution is to quote or rename the property. [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) can be used to find these errors in your code, by using `"es3":true` in `.jshintrc` or `// jshint es3:true` in your JS file.

Answer (score 6):

The word `export` is an ECMAScript [*future reserved word*](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-7.5.3), in some implementations using this keywords as identifiers cause SyntaxErrors.

However you can simply use a string literal, instead the identifier:

```
//....
        "export": {
            "use": ["encode","encode_iphone"],
            "robot": "/s3/store"
        }
//....
```

This keyword may be used on the future for *module declarations*:

- [Simple Modules](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=strawman:simple_modules)