# Parse error on mobile safari

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, mobile-safari

I'm having a hard time figuring out the cause of my js script to fail. I request several json objects from the server.It works on chrome, firefox and IE, however on mobile safari it fails. I'm using pure js and no jQuery.

The errors that I get are the following:

> Javascript error on line 31:
>   SyntaxError: Parse error
>
> Javascript error on line 78:
>   SyntaxError: Parse error
>
> Javascript error on line 52:
>   ReferenceError: Can't find variable: init

The lines in question are the following

31:

```
for (var i = 0; i < res.class.length; i++)
```

78:

```
res.class = JSON.parse(response).classes;
```

52:

```
function init()
{
        getData(loadData, "./js/data/classes.json");    
}
```

Note that those lines are from 2 different js files. The loadData  callback only parses the response.

Here is the getData function:

```
function getData(callback, filePath){
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var response;
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200){
            callback(xhttp.responseText);
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", filePath, true);
    xhttp.overrideMimeType("application/json");
    xhttp.send();
}
```

The sequential order should be like this

1)onload call init()

2)init loads via ajax the json file

3)parse json

4)access the parsed object

I did some research and found a certain "format-detection" meta tag, however that didn't help.

Here is a sample entry of the json.

```
{"classes": [
{
    "id":"foo",
    "uiName":"bar",
    "textString1":"foo - bar",
    "bonus":"Excellent vs. foo",
    "effect1":"bar:200",
    "effect2":"foo:150",
    "effect3":"bar:150"
}]}
```

My guess is that the JSON parser fails somewhere along the lines.

Comment: Maybe the `xhttp.overrideMimeType("application/json");` messes with mobile Safari?

Comment: I guess at least the first 2 errors are due to the phenomenon described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870409/syntaxerror-parse-error-only-happens-in-safari), which is Safari-specific (Safari seems to be stricter about reserved words than most other browsers).